# What does it mean: could not disagree more

Tags: sentence-meaning

Someone said "in the US ... 'have you got' would barely be understood."

A native speaker contradicted them, by saying

> I could not disagree more with your statement that "in the US ... 'have you got' would barely be understood."

I'm confused by "could not disagree". Did he agree or disagree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've dropped the most relevant word from the phrase, which is where the confusion comes from. This is not the double negative of "I cannot disagree" (which would mean "I agree") but a comparative phrase with "**more**."

If someone "*could not disagree **more***" that means that they already disagree to the greatest extent possible.

If someone "could not agree more" that means they already agree to the greatest extent possible.